# Dynamic Tax Rate Calculation Based on Product Price

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3

i want to increase tax percent based on product price. if Product price is more than 5000 tax will be increased by 2%. Currently i have tax percent 5% for all products and it is applicable for all products.

Comment: have you tried with price rule ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: tax claculation]

Check at this tutorial, it shows all parts [Click Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_taxes.htm)